# Model and visualize input and output

Tags: modeling, plc

I'm working on my bachelor's thesis which is supposed to reengineer legacy code. One part is to analyze the inputs and outputs of each subcomponent. The subcomponents are just boolean algorithms like
if(A && B && C){Z = true}
if(...
if(...
There are 64 inputs and 32 outputs in roughly 120 boolean operations that happen simultaneously. They don't cascade.

I want to model all inputs with their corresponding outputs. However, none of the modeling languages/systems are helpful. Do you have any suggestions?

I checked UML,flowchart,SADT,bpmn and graphcet

Thanks in advance

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to know the best language or means to express the state of a digital output (binary / boolean) according to all the digital inputs that interfere with it, am I right?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Boolean Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) or [Logic Gates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate) to express the state of a digital output in terms of multiple inputs.

Both methods can be used in many different ways and systems, as your question is tagged with the `PLC` Tag, I'll describe it more directed at that.

In some PLCs that comply with [IEC61131-3](https://plcopen.org/sites/default/files/downloads/intro_iec_oct2016.pdf) in the [Strucured Text language](https://plcopen.org/sites/default/files/downloads/introduction_structured_text.pptx) you can do something like this (Note also that this is very similar to what is possible to do in C#, C++, vb.net, python and many other languages, changing only the operators - `&&` instead of `AND` for example):

```
Z := A AND B AND C;
```

Another example, in PLCs that allow programming with [Function Blocks Diagram (FBD)](https://plcopen.org/sites/default/files/downloads/introduction_fbd.pptx):

[image]

But note that in a PLC the system is dynamic and there is flow control that a block diagram or simple Boolean algebra will not be able to define. In your code by having `IF` there is clearly a `SET of the output, which should receive` RESET` at some other time based on some other situation.

In the example below, the `Z` output will be set to `TRUE` when `A`, `B` AND `C` are `TRUE`. Then, if input `A` goes to `FALSE`, `Z` will not go to `FALSE`.

[image]

Comment: The legacy program is written in FBD but it's just too much to use it directly. I need to reduce and simplify the quantity to make it clearer.
So far the only good option is to stick to FBD language. But instead of using logical terms, I'd be describing what it does like "close Valve 1". Inputs would be A,B,C and Output Z. I don't need to look into the logical operations. I did a bad call there.

Comment: Yes! using descriptive terms is ideal. I don't know if it can help you, but if your system really can be simplified to a single boolean expression for each output, you could try using Karnaugh Map to reduce the expression, which consequently would lead to a smaller FBD program.

Comment: In terms of future maintenance and ease of debugging, I prefer to use FBD, as it is easier to visualize the signal flow in real time.

Comment: Tanks I'll keep k-map in mind. For everything else, which cannot be simplified by that, I'll keep searching for solutions. Maybe I create something new.

Answer (score 1):

You could visualize a trace/trend/scope of the (3 digital) inputs along with the output over time.

There would be 8 possible combination of values for the 3 digital inputs, with the corresponding Z value.  So if it was Z = A && !B && !C, this picture shows the behavior of Z depending upon the (boolean) values of A, B, and C:

[image: boolean plot]